# Issue in getting company,Designation and Phone Number in LinkedIn Android SDK

Tags: android, linkedin-api

i'am using the linkedIn android SDK to fetch the loggedin user details,i need to get the company name,designation and phone no.
i make the call to this api : `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,company,designation,headline,formatted-name,phone-numbers,picture-url)`

and while reading JSON i use this

```
response.get(company).toString();
response.get(designation).toString();
```

but this doesnt work,pls help

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Comment: i can login and get all other basic info,but company,designation and phone number is not getting..how do i retreive that?